# PHP Header location in IF statement

Tags: php

Im trying to write this script to say if email is valied insert into DB and redirect, else redirect with error message only my redirect isn't working, im not terribly great with php and still reading up on the subject so id appreciate any advice, thanks in advance!

```
<?php

$userid = $usersClass->userID();
$user_email=$_POST['email_upd'];

if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
header('Location: http://www.mysite.co.uk/mytwitter.php?msg=invalid');
}
else
{
mysql_query(" UPDATE produgg_users SET email='$user_email' where produgg_users.id = ".$usersClass->userID()) or die(mysql_error());
header('Location: http://www.mysite.co.uk/mytwitter.php?msg=success');
}

?>
```

Sorry for not describing what goes wrong, what's happening is my page isnt redirecting back to the page in the header(location)

I've now enabled Error reporting and im still only seeing a white page, heres my entire page code.

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'config.inc.php'; 


?>

<?php

$userid = $usersClass->userID();
$user_email=$_POST['email_upd'];

if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    header('Location: http://www..co.uk/mytwitter.php?msg=invalid');
    }
else
    {
    mysql_query(" UPDATE produgg_users SET email='$user_email' where produgg_users.id = ".$usersClass->userID()) or die(mysql_error());
    header('Location: http://www..co.uk/mytwitter.php?msg=success');
    }

?>
```

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but you need to always `die()` after a header redirect, and your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: You should describe what exactly goes wrong, though.

Comment: Hi Pekka, Im aware its currently vulnerable to injection attacks, im reading up on that at the moment which I planned to integrate later, or is this not the best way of going about things?

Comment: Please elaborate "my redirect isn't working". What's happening instead? Any error messages? If none, set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` and `display_errors` to `1`.

Comment: @Liam you should fix it before using the code on a official, production web site. If you're still developing, it's  not a problem (although it's easy to forget)

Comment: Im just seeing a white page Oswald, Ill turn error reporting on.

Comment: @Liam: retro fitting SQL injection prevention is hard - you may forget something, you will have to re-test everything. As soon as you can, consider moving from direct querying (mysql_*) to PDO and parameterized queries.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I think i better read up on PDO and parametized queries then befor going any further.

Comment: Just before I do read up on PDO, what is wrong with using direct querying for something as simple as an email address update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working using the following code, I've rewritten it based upon what I've read regarding SQL injections and it works fine, I'd appreciate any advice on this, thanks!

```
<?php 

require 'config.inc.php'; 

$userid = $usersClass->userID();
$user_email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email_upd']);

if(eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $user_email)) 
{ 
    mysql_query(" UPDATE produgg_users SET email='$user_email' where produgg_users.id = ".$usersClass->userID()) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/mytwitter.php?msg=email updated\">";
} 
else 
{ 
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/mytwitter.php?msg=email error\">";
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but make sure that you don't have any code before header method, when I say code I mean and output from php or HTML tags in any other file, this needs to be executed first,
but also you need to make sure that code after redirect is not executed do it with exit;

```
header(....
exit;
```

Comment: This should work really, but check on other browsers, I know some plugins on ff can disable page redirect...

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your complete script? What Senad said is true: if your script writes *anything* to the output buffer, any header(); won't work anymore. Based on the code you have given, nothing is written to the output buffer (unless you are getting a mysql error, which you are not telling us about, which I assume is not the case).

Also, there is no need to use  and then reopen it with . Just FYI.